# set a specific Date And Time in HangFire

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduler, hangfire

How do I set a specific time? for example 7/2/2021 8:00 AM.

Which methods should I use? `Enqueue` methods  or `Schedule` methods or `AddOrUpdate` Methods?

Comment: Should you use the hangfire library?
Can't you use DateTime?

Comment: No. HangFire is a library for scheduling

Comment: I found a solution for this. in this way we set a DateTimeOffset to Schedule Method in HangFire.
`var id = _backgroundJobClient.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Delayed Job"), DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hangfire uses **cron schedule expressions**. You can set any date-time expression you want.
for example

> 0 8 24 7 *   =>
> “At 08:00 on day-of-month 24 in July.”

the following code shows how to use the expression,You can use some online tools for creating expressions like [crontab](https://crontab.guru/).

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(jobId, methodCall, "0 8 24 7 *", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

if you want to execute something once you should use BackgroundJob.

```
var selectedDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-07-02 08:00:00");
BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => YourDelayedJob(), selectedDate);
```

Comment: Yes that's right. But I want this to be done only once.
Doesn't Recurring Method repeat it on this date?

Comment: @SajadKardel you want to do it every month for Example?

Comment: No. I want to run only once in a date

Comment: Apparently it can use the schedule method and get a DateTimeOfSet

Comment: @SajadKardel just updated my answer, Hope it helps, Recurring by self has a repeating life cycle.you have to use BackgroundJob

Answer (score 2):

If you only have the scheduled date:

```
DateTime dateSchedule = new DateTime(2021, 2, 7);
BackgroundJob.Schedule(job, dateSchedule - DateTime.Now);
```

Just add date validations so that the scheduled date (dateSchedule) is not in past.

Comment: You can also just use `BackgroundJob.Schedule(job, dateSchedule);` as the Schedule method also accepts DateTimeOffset.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> **Delayed jobs**
>
> Delayed jobs are executed only once too, but not
> immediately, after a certain time interval.

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(
              () => Console.WriteLine("Delayed!"),
                    TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
```

> Sometimes you may want to postpone a method invocation; for example,
> to send an email to newly registered users a day after their
> registration. To do this, just call the BackgroundJob.Schedule method
> and pass the desired delay

https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-with-delay.html

Comment: Yes, but I want to set a specific date and time. Not after a time